# Textarea does not fill table cell in all major browsers

Tags: html, css

This is strange but I have a jsFiddle where when the user clicks on the "Add Question" button to append a table row, under the "Question" column in the appended row, the height and the width of the textarea in this table cell is able to fill the table cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/LKB9e/12/

But the problem is that I have exactly the same code in my application but in my application the textarea does not fill in the table cell for IE, Firefox and Opera but it works fine in safari and Chrome.

Why is it not working in the other browsers and how can it work in those browsers?

application

Below is main css which compiles the textarea:

```
.question { 
    min-width:14%;
    max-width:14%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
      line-height: 0;
}

.question textarea {

        min-width:auto;
        max-width:auto;
        resize:none;
        height:100%;
        font-size:100%;
          display: block; 

    }
```

Which little issues from other browsers could cause this?

Comment: just use the extension -ms- for IE n -o- for opera and -moz- for mozila .. it may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the updated fiddle for demo : http://jsfiddle.net/LKB9e/23/embedded/result/

Its working in all browsers.

HTML:

```
<div id="details">
    <table id="qandatbl" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="9%" class="qid">Question No</th>
          <th width="29%" class="question">Question</th>
          <th width="62%" class="optandans">Option and Answer</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#qandatbl{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.question {
    /*min-width:14%;
    max-width:14%;*/
    max-width:0.1%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
      line-height: 0;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
function insertQuestion(form) {
........
........
 // your entire function's code here
........

    setWidth(); calling this function will adjust the width and height of the text area accordin to its parent td.
}
function setWidth() {
    var questionCellWidth = $("#qandatbl tbody .question").width();
    var questionCellHeight = $("#qandatbl tbody .question").height();
    $(".textAreaQuestion").css({
        "width": (questionCellWidth - 6) + "px",
        "height": (questionCellHeight) + "px"
    });
}
```

Rest is up to you how you make the looks an feel in your application i just solved your entire width & height issue of text area.

Comment: Ha ha thanks to you. You made me happy after seeing you comment because the problem took my 30mins to solve the issue. M feeling glad to help you.